# CSS - double/offset border with outer border dashed

Tags: css, border

I'd like to produce a circle with the outer dashed border offset from the main circle. I've attached a pic for reference.

I have tried using box shadow to achieve this but no luck so far. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: I was able to get [*this*](http://jsfiddle.net/sPGsS/). However, the `background-color` is left between the dots still. Maybe someone else can get it closer.

Comment: What a mind buckling idea :)

Comment: Are we too assume this must be applied to a single element only?

Comment: Also tried it, let me quote "border-radius 100% will not result in
a dotted/dashed circle, because the entire radius is considered a corner" from: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to get this effect by utilizing the pseudo-element selector `::before`. (`::after` would work just as well)

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sPGsS/3/)

Given the element:

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Apply the following CSS rule:

```
.circle {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border: 2px dotted black; /* This is the outer border (dotted) */
    background-color: white; /* This is the color of the inner border */
    padding: 10px; /* This is the size of the inner border */
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle::before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    background-color: #6abde7; /* This is the color of the inner circle */
    width: 150px; /* This controls how wide the circle will be. Remember to subtract padding + border */
    height: 150px; /* This controls how tall the circle will be. Remember to subtract padding + border */
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

You can adjust a few of the rules above. They are mainly there just to give shape to the circle for the demo. I've commented the ones that control the styles of the circle.

#### Explanation

You're basically adding an element inside of the container element via CSS. *This won't work on elements that don't support content.* (i. e. `<input>`)

Comment: @HashemQolami Looks like it!

Comment: I prefer yours, with relative uints :)

Comment: thanks, that does the trick nicely...how would I go about adding centred text inside the inner circle?

Comment: @Ben I actually think that HashemQolami's solution is better suited for that. See here an example using his solution: http://jsfiddle.net/sPGsS/4/

Answer (score 2):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/CGfv2/)

```
.circle {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#cef;
    border:3px dotted #000;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 10px #fff;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Using `:after`

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/CP3RH/)

```
.circle {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:3px dotted #000;
}

.circle:after {
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    height:180px;
    width:180px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#cef;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}
```

Comment: Same problem I had in the comments above. The background-color is between the dots.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't have a second div, like so?
http://jsfiddle.net/gUYFF/1/

```
.outline {
float:left;
border: dotted 2px black;
width: 220px;
height: 220px;
border-radius: 110px;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px white inset;
}
.circle {
    background-color: #6abde7;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin:10px;
}
<div class="outline"><div class="circle"></div></div>
```